# Liquibase : Master change logfile not found

Tags: liquibase

I am using Liquibase 4.23.2 on Windows.
Running the below and getting error:

C:\Biraja\Liquibase\changelogs>liquibase --defaultsFile=“C:\Biraja\Liquibase\liquibase-4.23.2\liquibase.properties” --changelog-file=“C:\Biraja\Liquibase\changelogs\change_master.xml” updateSQL

Starting Liquibase at 15:00:39 (version 4.23.2 #13458 built at 2023-09-11 22:00+0000)
Liquibase Version: 4.23.2
Liquibase Open Source 4.23.2 by Liquibase
– Create Database Lock Table
CREATE TABLE …
…
…

Unexpected error running Liquibase: The file C:\Biraja\Liquibase\changelogs\change_master.xml was not found in the configured search path:

- C:\Biraja\Liquibase\changelogs
- C:\Biraja\Liquibase\liquibase-4.23.2\internal\lib\liquibase-core.jar
- C:\Biraja\Liquibase\liquibase-4.23.2\lib\ojdbc8.jar
- C:\Biraja\Liquibase\liquibase-4.23.2\lib
  …
  …

The file is present in the mentioned location. Not sure why the error.

C:\Biraja\Liquibase\changelogs>dir
Volume in drive C is OSDisk

Directory of C:\Biraja\Liquibase\changelogs

09/25/2023 02:36 PM .
09/25/2023 02:05 PM …
09/25/2023 09:05 AM 1,341 changelog_00001_setup_tab1.xml
09/25/2023 02:13 PM 466 change_master.xml

I am new to Liquibase. So request your help. Thank You.